# update button on nested gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this nested grid view in which the data are shown in textboxes and i also have an update button but when i click the button instead of updating the data on the data table it just updates the new value on the grid view itself and shows it along with the old value and i don't get any error though. Please help me thanks.

the code:

```
private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string ID = gvSDate.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvSDate2 = e.Row.FindControl("gvSDate2") as GridView;
            gvSDate2.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select ID, Function, FunctionDate, FunctionTime, CelebrateName from function where ID={0}", ID));
            gvSDate2.DataBind();
        }
    }
protected void gvSDate2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs f)
    {

        if (f.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gvSDate2 = f.Row.FindControl("gvSDate2") as GridView;
            TextBox textFunction = f.Row.FindControl("textFunction") as TextBox;
            TextBox textFunctionDate = f.Row.FindControl("textFunctionDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox textFunctionTime = f.Row.FindControl("textFunctionTime") as TextBox;
            TextBox textCelebrateName = f.Row.FindControl("textCelebrateName") as TextBox;
            Label lblID = f.Row.FindControl("lblID") as Label;
            Button update1 = f.Row.FindControl("update1") as Button;
            string Function = textFunction.Text;
            string FunctionDate = textFunctionDate.Text;
            string FunctionTime = textFunctionTime.Text;
            string CelebrateName = textCelebrateName.Text;
            string ID1 = lblID.Text;
            update1.Click += (send, g) =>
            {
                string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string updateQuery = "UPDATE function SET Function=@Function, FunctionDate=@FunctionDate, FunctionTime=@FunctionTime, CelebrateName=@CelebrateName WHERE ID=@ID";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = updateQuery;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Function", Function);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", FunctionDate);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", FunctionTime);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CelebrateName", CelebrateName);

            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: i really dont know where im making a mistake so please help me